# Chrome extension not populating form with web data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, messaging

First time with chrome extensions - I am making a bookmarks extension. I want my `content script` to send data to my background pop-up page after scraping data from the web page.

I am following the [official documentation for message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging). So I have a content script `background.js` with this code:

```
var pageInfo = {
    'title': document.title,
    'url': window.location.href,
    'summary': window.getSelection().toString()
};

// Send the information back to the extension
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(pageInfo, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

And then my background page script `main.js` intercepts this message like so:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    $('#title').val(request.title); // this is not working
    console.log('request: ', request);
    console.log('sender: ', sender);
    sendResponse('funky');
  }
);
```

Now the data is being passed through back and forth properly. Those console statements above work! But my form field `#title` is still not populated. My background page html (pop-up) form is this:

```
        <form id="addbookmark">
            <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p><label for="url">Url</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="url" name="url" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p><label for="summary">Summary</label><br />
            <textarea id="summary" name="summary" rows="6" cols="35"></textarea></p>
            <p><label for="tags">Tags</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="tags" name="tags" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p>
                <input id="save" type="submit" value="Save Bookmark" />
                <span id="status-display"></span>
            </p>
        </form>

        <script src="jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
```

My form fields show up empty when I refresh a web page

[image: empty extension form]

So what am I doing wrong? How do I debug and fix this?

Here is my `manifest.json` for reference

```
 {
  "name": "plugin name",
  "version": "0",
  "description": "What do I do as an extension",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "main.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "name": "Manipulate DOM",
    "icons": ["icon.png"],
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "background.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["jquery.min.map"],
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Why was I voted down? Kindly explain

Comment: I'm writing an answer, but I voted down because I find the question not useful.

Comment: ok. I am still waiting for your answer... @Xan

Comment: I updated my answer with a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) and **get your names straight**.

It is extremely confusing to name a *content script* `background.js`, and the *popup page* `background.html`, which we can see from the fact that it effectively confused you.

---

A *background page* is an invisible page that is active as long as Chrome runs. It's different from the *popup page*, that is created as you click on the browser action and destroyed when it loses focus.

As such, it's rarely useful to run the same script (`main.js`) on both - they serve different purposes.

---

What currently happens is: your content script runs once when the page loads, and sends a message. At this point, presumably the popup is closed, so your background page receives the message and answers. Note that at this point it throws an error, because `#title` doesn't exist on the background page. You can see this if you open the extension list at `chrome://extensions` and enable Developer Mode.

If, by any chance, your popup was open exactly at the moment the content script executes, it would *also* receive the message and work as intended.

---

**EDIT: A better solution**

A better yet solution is to keep your original logic, but inject the script programmatically from the popup. Why is it better? When you are invoking the script from the popup, you are granted permissions for that tab by `activeTab`. This means much less scary permissions are needed.

1) Put your content script into `content.js`

```
// content.js
var pageInfo = {
    'title': document.title,
    'url': window.location.href,
    'summary': window.getSelection().toString()
};

// Send the information back to the extension
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(pageInfo);
```

2) Remove `content_scripts` from the manifest and adjust the permissions:

```
"permissions": [ "activeTab" ],
```

3) In the popup code, inject the script and listen for the message:

```
// popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    $('#title').val(request.title);
    // ...
  }
);

// Injection defaults to current tab, no need to query
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "jquery.min.js"}, function(){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"});
});
```

End result: no [permission warnings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings), no "stray code" in tabs until you click your button.

Note: with this solution, you don't need a background page at all. Until you need it, just remove the `"background"` key from the manifest.

Comment: Note: you don't even need jQuery for your content script, you can omit the first `executeScript`

Comment: ok that actually works. Could you tell me where I would put my ajax call to submit data to my server? Can I make that a separate script?

Comment: I would make that from a separate script that I would put in the background page (so that it can safely execute even if popup gets destroyed). You can use messaging or `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` to invoke it from the popup.

Comment: So I am going to mark this as the right answer. But could you clarify a few things:

a) What exactly is `popup.js` in this plugin's context? What should it control?
b) `content.js` is the content script - I get that now. So should I only use that for messaging?

Comment: Your two last questions make little sense. a) `popup.js` is a more sensible name for the script included in a popup window b) you should use content scripts for whatever you need them

Comment: ok I guess I am still confused about terminology. This is my first time. Thank you for all your help